# how to select Specific objects from array

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I have create an array containing person firstname,lastname and number which i populate in tableview. Now i want to show only those person data whose lastname is equal to "Ahmed"  This might be a simple question but i am not able to do it.Any help will be appreciated. Here is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    productArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    PersonDetail *personObj = [[PersonDetail alloc] init];
    personObj.firstName = @"Adeem";
    personObj.lastName = @"Basraa";
    personObj.phoneNumber = @"123456789";

    [productArray addObject:personObj];
    [personObj release];

    PersonDetail *personObj = [[PersonDetail alloc] init];
    personObj.firstName = @"Ijaz";
    personObj.lastName = @"Ahmed";
    personObj.phoneNumber = @"987654321";

    [productArray addObject:personObj];
    [personObj release];

    PersonDetail *personObj = [[PersonDetail alloc] init];
    personObj.firstName = @"Waqas";
    personObj.lastName = @"Ahmad";
    personObj.phoneNumber = @"45656789";
    [productArray addObject:personObj];
    [personObj release];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use 
`- (NSArray *)filteredArrayUsingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate` on your array to retrieve a new filtered array.

To create a predicate use: `(NSPredicate *)predicateWithFormat:(NSString *)format, ...`.

E.g.:

```
NSString* searchName = @"Ahmad";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastName == '%@'", searchName];
NSArray* filteredPersons = [productArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score 2):

use predicate to get particular objects from array like this

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastName == '%@'", nameObject];
[productArray filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

it will remove the object other than having last name as nameObj

```
NSMutableArray *list =   [productArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

this statement will gives an array having all personDetail objects having lastName as nameObj

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following method from the `NSArray` superclass:

`- (NSUInteger)indexOfObjectPassingTest:(BOOL (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))predicate`

This method takes a block as its argument, which is basically like a mini-function that will be called for every element of the array. Within your block code you could cast the `id obj` as a `PersonDetail` instance and then check the name is equal to "Ahmed". Once you find the `PersonDetail` you're looking for, you can set the `stop` output parameter to be true by dereferencing the third argument of the block like this.. `*stop = YES`.

Check the documentation for this method of [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html). You'll probably also want to check out the [blocks programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/_index.html) if you're new to the blocks syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs this, here's an example - hope it helps. 

Assume you have an array **allMovies** & you are searching it for a particular movie **someMovie** and would like to get its index in the array. allMovies is an **array of movie dictionaries** as an example from a JSON service.

```
NSUInteger theIndex = [self.allMovies indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
  if ([[[obj objectForKey:@"movie"] objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue] == someMovie.id)
                *stop = YES;
                NSLog(@"IDX: %d", idx);
                return *stop;
}];
NSLog(@"FOUND INDEX FOR SEARCHED OBJECT: %d", theIndex);
```